# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have set my routes in the App.js file. but I got an error when I change the url of my project. I created an state component called movieState.js where I have 3 objects with different url´s.

So anytime I write 'http://localhost:3000/work/bicycle' I got the following error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

This is my App.js:

```
//Styles
import "./styles/app.scss";

//Global Style from styled-components
import GlobalStyle from "./components/GlobalStyle";

//Router
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

//import Pages
import AboutUs from './pages/AboutUs';
import OurWork from './pages/OurWork';
import ContactUs from './pages/ContactUs';
import MovieDetail from "./pages/MovieDetail";

//Nav component
import Nav from './components/Nav';




function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AboutUs />} />
        <Route path="/work" element={<OurWork />} />
        <Route path="/work/:id" element={<MovieDetail />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my movieState.js where I have all my data;

```
//Import Images
import { color } from "framer-motion";
import bicycle from "./img/bycicle.jpg";
import colorwall from "./img/colorwall.jpg";
import light from "./img/light.jpg";

export const MovieState = () => {
  return [
    {
      title: "The Bicycle",
      mainImg: bicycle,
      secondaryImg: bicycle,
      url: "/work/bicycle",
      awards: [
        {
          title: "Truly A masterpiece",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
        {
          title: "Fresh look on a brutal sport.",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
        {
          title: "It’s okay lmao.",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "The Color Wall",
      mainImg: colorwall,
      url: "/work/colorwall",
      secondaryImg: colorwall,
      awards: [
        {
          title: "Truly A masterpiece",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
        {
          title: "Fresh look on a brutal sport.",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
        {
          title: "It’s okay lmao.",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "The Light",
      mainImg: light,
      url: "/work/light",
      secondaryImg: light,
      awards: [
        {
          title: "Truly A masterpiece",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
        {
          title: "Fresh look on a brutal sport.",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
        {
          title: "It’s okay lmao.",
          description:
            "“Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.”",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
};
```

This is my nav.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Nav() {

  return (
    <StyledNav>
        <Link to="/">
            <h1>Logo</h1>
        </Link>
        
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/" className='li'>About Us</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/work" className='li'>Our Work</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact" className='li'>Contact Us</Link></li>
   
        </ul>

    </StyledNav>
  )
}
```

Moviedetail.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MovieState } from '../movieState';

function MovieDetail() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const url = navigate.location.pathname;
  const [movies,setMovies] = useState(MovieState); 
  const [movie,setMovie] = useState(null);

  //useEffect runs after the component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentMovie = movies.filter((stateMovie) => stateMovie.url === url);
    setMovie(currentMovie);
  }, [movies,url]);

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Movie Detail</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MovieDetail;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`useNavigate()` returns a `NavigateFunction` which can be used to navigate to other routes.

```
interface NavigateFunction {
  (to: To, options?: NavigateOptions): void;
  (delta: number): void;
}
```

You can use it like: `navigate("/another-route")`.

It has no property called `location`. That makes `navigate.location` undefined.

So when you try to access `navigate.location.pathname`, that will throw an error (since you are trying to access `pathname` property in undefined).

---

To solve this, use `window.location.pathname` instead of `navigate.location.pathname`.

> The Window.location read-only property returns a Location object with information about the current location of the document.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location